# Need to delete property 'flex-basis'. What native css-property can replace it?

Tags: css, flexbox

> for example I have div, which has flex-basis:33%;
>
> What native css-property can replace 'flex-basis'?
>
> What solutions you can reccomend?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 product_preview">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 product_preview">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 product_preview">3</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 product_preview">4</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 product_preview">5</div>

.product_preview{
   flex-basis:33.333%;
   max-width:33.333%
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what precise effect you are after but:

[**MDN Ref:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

> The flex-basis CSS property specifies the flex basis which is the **initial main size of a flex item**. This property determines the size of the content-box unless specified otherwise using box-sizing.

So, `flex-basis` is, essentially, the `flexbox` altenative to `min-width` (or `min-height`) depending on the `flex-direction` BUT the two aren't directly interchangable.

This is because even though an element may have `flex-basis: 100px`...the `flex-shrink/grow` properties allow for shrinking/growth.

However, if you are looking for the same overall functionality without `flexbox` then, as far as I am aware, it doesn't exist outside of javascript solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete `flex-basis`, you can use `width` or `height` instead.

That's because the initial value of [`flex-basis`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-basis) is [`auto`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto), which means

> When specified on a [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item), the `auto` keyword retrieves the
>   value of the [main size property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size-property) as the used [`flex-basis`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-basis).

And the main size property is given by `width` (in row layouts) or `height` (in column layouts):

> The [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item)’s *main size property* is either the [`width`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visudet.html#propdef-width)
>   or [`height`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visudet.html#propdef-height) property, whichever is in the main dimension.